# django-haystack: order by list of IDs passed as arguments

Tags: python, django, django-haystack

How can I order search results in haystack by a list of IDs passed as argument?

```
ids_list = [341, 127, 12, 576, 32, 8]
sqs = SearchQuerySet().models(MyModel).filter(django_id__in=ids_list) # order by...?
```

I need results to be ordered by the same order of the IDs in `ids_list`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how that could be done with django (I hope someone else does), but you always can do it after the query with "normal" Python code:

```
sqs.sort(key=lambda x: ids_list.index(x.id))
```

or something like that.

Comment: x.pk instead of x.id would be fine. x.id is a joined result of (app name, model name, obj id). Then the code is like -- sorted(sqs, key=lambda x: ids_list.index(x.pk))

Comment: @okm: *"x.id is a joined result of (app name, model name, obj id)"* Do you have a reference for that? So that your suggestion could be pushed into the answer.

Comment: sure, the code is at https://github.com/toastdriven/django-haystack/blob/master/haystack/utils/__init__.py#L13 . pk is referenced at http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/searchresult_api.html#attribute-reference

Answer (score 0):

you need to override get_queryset method of haystack and add your sorting fields to your index model like below
that i used in

[djangolinks.com](http://djangolinks.com)

```
class LinkIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
   text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
   creation = indexes.DateField(model_attr='creation')
   title = indexes.CharField(model_attr='title')
   total_votes = indexes.IntegerField(model_attr='total_votes')
   tags = indexes.MultiValueField()



sort_by = {
    'd': '-creation',
    't': 'title',
    'v': '-total_votes',
}

class LinkListView(ListView):
    context_object_name = "link"
    def get_queryset(self):
        sort = self.request.GET.get('sort')
        if sort in sort_by.keys():
           return Link.published.filter().order_by('%s' % sort_by[sort])
        else:
           return Link.published.filter().order_by('-creation')
```

http://djangolinks.com/search/?q=django&tags=&sort=v

Comment: It's ok if you want to link to a better explained blog entry, but you should try to make the answers here on SO consistent with the Q&A fromat, meaning that it'd be better to post here the actual code that answers the OP question. Also the link might be broken one day but the answer will still be here.